# Undo and Checkout for Edit are disabled on file

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

We are using `TFS`: If I open a file in `Visual Studio 2015 or 2017` and right click on the page select `Source Control -> Undo Pending Changes ...` it is **disabled**. 
But if I use `Team Explorer` and right click, it is fine, I **can** use Undo.

Why?

Comment: Right click on which page? Do you mean that right click on the file/folder which displayed in `Source Control Explorer` or from `File > Source Control -> Undo Pending Changes`  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly make sure the file is in source control.

For specific file, the `Undo Pending Changes` option can be only enabled when there are changes which not be checked in yet, that means you can see the changes in "`Pending Changes`" page. If no changes there, then the `Undo Pending Changes` item will be **disabled** (grey out).

The option `Checkout for Edit` can be only enabled when no changes on the file (All the changes already checked in) .

If you mean right in `Source Control Explorer` or `File > Source Control -> Undo Pending Changes`, then you need to **select (highlight) the file first**, otherwise the related items will be disabled.

[image]